# Jenkins user and group removed automatically

Tags: jenkins, centos5

I installed Jenkins 1.531.1.1 on CentOS 5.5 by executing the below mentioned commands:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum install jenkins
```

I changed the JENKINS_HOME variable in the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file to something other than /var/lib/jenkins. I changed the default port on which jenkins runs from 8080 to 9999. I also generated the ssh keys needed to pull code from github.

Unfortunately, when I try to define the github repository url in a Jenkins job, it failed to authenticate. When I checked grep jenkins /etc/passwd, the jenkins user was no longer there. I did the whole process twice and the user seems to be getting removed. Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The deployment team had set up a script to automatically delete any new users created just for maintenance purposes. The fact that it happened across multiple CentOS servers actually triggered me to ask this question.